# Queries MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with refreshing my memory on how to query correctly.

```
CREATE TABLE Editor
(eid CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    fname VARCHAR(15), 
    lname VARCHAR(15));

CREATE TABLE Edited_by
(eid CHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
    isbn CHAR(10) NOT NULL);
```

Now I need to query an ISBN #3489374345 and get the eid, fname, lname.

From what I know it's...

```
SELECT eid, fname, lname
FROM Editor, Edited_by
WHERE isbn='3489374345'
```

But I think my `WHERE` is incorrect as I know it's not pulling the ISBN from the Edited_by table.

Comment: you have two **eid** in your example. which one you want to select ? the eid of Editor or Edited_By ? where is your Foreign KEY ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT e.eid, e.fname, e.lname
FROM Editor e inner join Edited_by b
on e.eid=b.eid
WHERE b.isbn='3489374345'
```

Comment: Thanks, cleared it up now. What is `ON` exactly? Don't think I learned about this. Usually I see that `e.eid=b.eid` within the `WHERE`

Comment: On clause is used when you do a join ! and writing where style is outdated ! however both works :) pls do accept and upvote ! [see here for join syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html)

Comment: May I ask you how would I do 3 tables? Say the edit I did to your answer. How would I go from getting the `fname` `lname` of the author who has written a `Book` "Database"

Answer (score 1):

Why not this

```
SELECT EB.eid, E.fname, E.lname
FROM Editor E JOIN Edited_by EB
ON Eb.eid = E.eid
WHERE Eb.isbn='3489374345'
```

Take a look at **[MySql Joins](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your foreign key of the **Editor_by** table to "Editor".

But you need to change the name of the column **eid** in MySQL is I know two column with the same name causes error when using Inner join.

```
CREATE TABLE Edited_by
(eid CHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
isbn CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_Editor_Editor_by  FOREIGN KEY(eid) REFERENCES Editor_by(eid)
);
```

Then you can Use this command

```
SELECT eid, fname, lname
FROM Editor a, Edited_by b
WHERE a.eid=b.eid AND b.isbn='3489374345'
```

Or use the Inner Join. But change the column Name.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are trying to retrieve data from Editor table (at least fname and lname) and your    'where' condition is applied on 'Edited_by' table. So, you need to join the table. And before joining the table, as 'eid' of 'Edited_by' table would definitely be a subset of 'eid' of 'Editor' table, you should add a foreign key relation in which 'eid' ('Edited_by') will refer 'eid' (Editor).

Related Queries are given in above answers.